# Java How do you extract "issued to" or user from a SSL cert within an HttpRequest?

Tags: java, ssl, httprequest

In Java How do you extract "issued to" or user from a SSL cert within an `HttpRequest`?

what I'm working with:

```
 Object certChain = request
    .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
if (certChain != null)
{
  X509Certificate certs[] = (X509Certificate[]) certChain;
  X509Certificate cert = certs[0];
  String user = cert.getSubjectDN().getName();
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's how you do it. What's your question?

Comment: @erickson I just need confirmation that this is indeed the correct way of doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code to extract the "Issued To" aka Subject for a cert within an httprequest,

```
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.naming.InvalidNameException;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapName;
import javax.naming.ldap.Rdn;

X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
if ((certs == null) || (certs.length == 0)) {
   return null;
}

String name = certs[0].getSubjectX500Principal().getName(); // if you are looking for issuer then use cert[0].getIssuerX500Principal().getName();
LdapName ldapName = null;
try {
   ldapName = new LdapName(name);
} catch (InvalidNameException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

for (Rdn rdn : ldapName.getRdns()) {
   String type = rdn.getType();
   if ("CN".equals(type)) { 
        String issuedTo = (String)rdn.getValue();
   }
}
```

JDK 6 has the API getSubjectX500Prinicpal() in it's rt.jar locally, not sure about the previous versions,
[image]

Comment: my compiler cant find the method getSubjectX500Principal() what library is this in? and how Do I obtain this from an HttpRequest object

Comment: I'm not facing any problems with my compiler. I'm using JDK 6, this class is available in rt.jar

Comment: what version of compiler are you using?

Comment: ahh.. I was using javax not java as the base package. Thanks anyhow

Comment: just realized that you have the name as "stackoverflow"...great!! :D

Comment: At Arham: I know, I ball so hard

Answer (score 2):

[`getSubjectDN()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectDN%28%29) should not be used any longer.

> **Denigrated**, replaced by getSubjectX500Principal().

So use:

```
cert[0].getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
```

Here is the JavaDoc for [`getSubjectX500Principal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectX500Principal%28%29).

Comment: As a side not I had to go look up what `Denigrated` meant when used in the JavaDoc. Seems to basically be a less severe form of `Deprecated`. At least according to [this Bug Report](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5008142) about it.

Comment: @stackoverflow I had a typo, sorry about that. As a heads up I asked a question over on [Programmers about the whole Denigrated thing](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/173396/1287), you might want to check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the response jschoen